# Discord.py client.join_voice_channel() mudou porém tento colocar igual a nova documentação e mesmo assim não funciona!

Tags: python

Olá! Estou começando a praticar Python além das videos aulas eu tento praticar criando alguns bots para o DISCORD e tentando entender a biblioteca que é usada. Porém meu código para adicionar o bot ao canal POR ENQUANTO está assim:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.conectar'):
        canal = message.author.voice.voice_channel
        await client.join_voice_channel(canal)
```

Sempre ao digitar o .conectar, ele gera um erro no console (eu sei que a discord.py atualizou, mas ja tentei de tudo e não entendo o motivo dos erros nesta parte)
Eu já tentei trocar client.join_voice_channel por VoiceChannel.connect como fala na documentação, mas ai gera outro erro, algo haver com "Member". Quem conseguir me ajudar ficarei extremamente GRATO!

Answer (score 0):

Eu mesmo, estudando e tentando de tudo acabei achando o problema, É MUITO SIMPLES, vou comentar aqui mesmo para ajudar quem tiver o problema:

```
    if message.content.startswith('.brota'):
        canal = message.author.voice.channel
        await message.channel.send("Entrando para soltar uma somzera...")
        await canal.connect()
```

Basta comparar os 2 códigos e irá entender os pequenos problemas.